# Why does my Ml CNN Kaggle Cats / Dogs prection only spit out an error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, kaggle

I´m pretty new to ML and Computer Vision.I am trying to do a categotrial prediction for Cats/ Dogs 0 as the Cats and 1 as the Dogs. But my model.fit() function spits out this error.
[image]
...

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 10000]
```

This is my ML model:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

#the images are stored in the Folders 'Cat/' and 'Dog/'
animal = ['Cat/','Dog/']
images_cat= []
images_dog=[]

# reads in the images 
for x in animal:
    for i in range(1,12500): # the are images from '1.jpg' till '12499.jpg' for each Cats and Dogs
        try:
            image_path = x+ str(i) +'.jpg'# this gets the path of the images for example 'Cat/1.jpg'
            #print(image_path)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            img_resized = cv2.resize(img,dsize=(100,100))
            if x == 'Cat/':
                images_cat.append(img_resized)
            elif x == 'Dog/':
                images_dog.append(img_resized)
                
        except cv2.error as e:
            #some images spit out an errer and the apprently can't be read so therefore I just give them the first image to add to the list
            if x == 'Cat/':
                images_cat.append(images_cat[1])
            elif x == 'Dog/':
                images_dog.append(images_dog[1])

# assign targets to values

y_cat = np.zeros(len(images_cat)) # Cat == 0
y_dog = np.ones(len(images_dog)) # Dog == 1


# trainig_images = 80%   test_images= 20%
training_sample_count = round(0.8* len(y_cat))

#list slicing the images to get 80% of the images as calculated above
X_cat_train = images_cat [:training_sample_count]
y_cat_train_fin = y_cat[:training_sample_count]

X_dog_train = images_dog [:training_sample_count]
y_dog_train_fin = y_dog[:training_sample_count]

# create the final training list
X_train = X_cat_train + X_dog_train
y_train=[]

y_train.append(y_cat_train_fin.data)
y_train.append(y_dog_train_fin.data)

y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(19998,))
np.shape(y_train)# output: (19998,)

#normalizing the data
X_train = [x / 255.0 for x in X_train]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(19998,10000))
np.shape(X_train) #output: (19998, 10000)

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Flatten 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=10000)
```

I haven't gotten to the test Images yet, but I basicly try to train this model for future Data (like own Images of Cats or Dogs to be then predicted).
I would be happy if anyone could help me with my problem as I am stuck atm. Cheers :)

Comment: Just a pointer, you have 19998 sample images. It doesnt make sense to have a batch size of 10000. Batch size is the number of samples that will result in gradient updates. In your case, each epoch will only have 2 gradient updates because 19998/10000 ~ 2. I would advice having batch size as something like 128 or 64 or 32.

Comment: I have added a detailed answer with code since I saw a few more issues. Do check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your model -

1. You are doing a binary classification yet using a configuration for multi-class single-label classification. Changing your loss and last layer activation to get correct results. Please check the table below for reference.

[image]

2. You are passing a 1D array for each sample to the Conv2D layer when it needs a 3D tensor. That's the reason for the error `expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2.` The expected dimension was `(batch, height, width, channels)` and instead it got `(batch, pixels)`. I have added a `model.add(Reshape((100,100,1), input_shape=(10000,)))` which reshapes the 10000 pixels to `(100,100,1)` to be able to be passed into the conv2d layer properly.
3. Lastly, you have 19998 sample images. Though possible, it doesn't make sense to have a batch size of 10000. Batch size is the number of samples that will result in gradient updates. In your case, each epoch will only have 2 gradient updates because 19998/10000 ~ 2. I would advise having batch size as something like 128 or 64 or 32. I have set it to 128 in the `model.fit`

Find the updated code below.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Flatten 

X_train = np.random.random((500, 10000))
Y_train = np.random.randint(0,2,(500,)) #0, 0, 1, 0, 1...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((100,100,1), input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(
    X_train,
    Y_train,
    epochs=3,
    batch_size=128)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 498ms/step - loss: 0.7019 - accuracy: 0.4680
Epoch 2/3
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 534ms/step - loss: 0.6939 - accuracy: 0.5260
Epoch 3/3
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 524ms/step - loss: 0.6922 - accuracy: 0.5240
```

Answer (score 1):

The Conv2D layer expects inputs of shape `(batch_size, x, y, depth)`. Your X_train is being reshaped to only have size `(batch_size, x*y)` which is not what the Conv2D expects.

It may work to just take out this reshape: `X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(19998,10000))`. If not, you could reshape to `(19998, 100, 100, 1)`.

Comment: If I take out 'X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(19998,10000))' it gives me this error:Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100..................100, 100, 100
  y sizes: 19998
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

Comment: So i've now reshaped the X_train data like you said to (19998,100,100,1) and it's working now. The problem now is that I get only an acc. of 50 % and it takes ages to train. Is there a way to gerneralize the data more. I think maybe suffling could an option but I don't acutaly now how to do that in my situation. Thanks ;)

Comment: That may be something to ask in another question. `ndarray`s can be shuffled in-place np.random.shuffle(x). I'm not sure what might be preventing it from learning. If there's a tutorial you're working from, I'd try to match it as well as possible before playing around.